# Table sorting with two rows of Header

Tags: jquery, sorting

My Table structure is like below:

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="jackpotwatch" style="width:700px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>

              <th>Location</th>
              <th colspan="2">Full Name</th>
              <th>Amount</th>

          </tr>
          <tr >
            <th>Asset</th>
            <th>Patron ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>Salem</td>
              <td colspan="2">Bob galvin</td>
              <td>$3400</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>assert1</td>
             <td>1148</td>
             <td>sjauser</td>
             <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>chennai</td>
              <td colspan="2">sally n safer</td>
              <td>$400</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>sdfsdgt1</td>
             <td>4747</td>
             <td>sjauser</td>
             <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Mazdgfdg</td>
              <td colspan="2">afdagadg</td>
              <td>789769</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>qwqeqe</td>
             <td>47467</td>
             <td>sjauser</td>
             <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>hurtyry</td>
              <td colspan="2">afadfadg</td>
              <td>$12000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>afadsf</td>
             <td>25426546</td>
             <td>sjauser</td>
             <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

When i click on the "Amount" header the amount values ($3400, $400, $12000) should be sorted, etc.
Like that Date/Time field also should sort based on the value.

I used [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin but that plugin not sorting all columns. It not sorting last column and second row header in this table. 
I also used [Tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) plugin but it change the table structure itself while sorting.

I cannot able to change the table structure as this is our client biggest requirement. Please provide some guide on this sorting problem which is very useful for me.

Any customized sorting we can apply means please suggest how can i do that.

Comment: Can you at least show us the table structure? Do they wrap each set of two rows in `TBODY` elements for example? It would really help to know the structure of the table.

Comment: try to create a more simplified and more user-friendly table... this one you're currently using is pretty messed up!

Comment: @Zlatan he said he can't change the table structure.

Comment: @crush OK, Raji, then advise your client for a more simplified table... I can't relate what is what in this table ...

Comment: @Zlatan It's two rows per record - there is nothing wrong with the layout of the table. Go away.

Comment: @Zlatan, this is actually a common format for tables that need to display more data than can fit in a single row. It needs some styling per CSS to display separation between records, but that is not the users question or concern. Other than that, it is perfectly fine. Take your amateurish opinions elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want the two rows for each entry to remain grouped together, in which case Tablesorter isn't designed to do what you want. Tinysort could work, though, if you were prepared to put each pair of rows into its own `tbody`:

```
<table id="jackpotwatch" style="width:700px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th colspan="2">Full Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <th>Asset</th>
        <th>Patron ID</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Salem</td>
          <td colspan="2">Bob galvin</td>
          <td>$3400</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>assert1</td>
         <td>1148</td>
         <td>sjauser</td>
         <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>chennai</td>
          <td colspan="2">sally n safer</td>
          <td>$400</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>sdfsdgt1</td>
         <td>4747</td>
         <td>sjauser</td>
         <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    ...
</table>
```

Since Tinysort can apparently sort on any kind of element, you should be able to tell it to sort the `tbody` elements instead of the rows. Your script could do something like this, loosely based on the table example in the Tinysort docs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aAsc = [];
    $("#jackpotwatch>thead th").each(function(nr) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            aAsc[nr] = aAsc[nr] == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
            $("#jackpotwatch>tbody").tsort('td:eq(' + nr + ')', {order: aAsc[nr]});
        });
    });
});
```

This relies on there being precisely the same number of cells in the header rows as in the rows of each tbody.

Comment: The author said that he cannot manipulate the table structure.

Comment: I assumed by that he meant he can't change the *apparent* structure of the table, i.e. the fact the data is presented in this two-row format. If the requirement is that he cannot make any changes to the HTML at all, then this won't work, no.

Comment: You might be right. I definitely think it would be better if each record was surrounded by a TBODY element, so if that is the case, then he should definitely go this route. Maybe I just misunderstood what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zbcz/) here.

I don't have a plugin for you, but I came up with the following approach for your specific situation:

```
/**
 * This approach assumes that records are always comprised of 2 rows. It is possible to make this configurable.
 */
;(function() {
  //Get the table
    var table = $("#jackpotwatch");

    //Make head header in the THEAD sortable.
    $("thead th", table).on("click", onSortableClicked);

    //Handle the sortable clicked event.
    function onSortableClicked(e) {
        //Find the column position.
        var c = -1, child = e.target;
        while ((child = child.previousSibling) != null)
            if (child.nodeType == 3) ++c;

        //Find the row position.
        var r = -1, child = e.target.parentNode;
        while ((child = child.previousSibling) != null)
            if (child.nodeType == 3) ++r;


        var subject = $("tbody", table);

        var replacement = sort(subject, r, c);

        subject.replaceWith(replacement);
    }

    function sort(subject, r, c) {
        var rows = $("tr", subject); //Get all the rows from the tbody.
        var sorted = document.createElement("tbody");

        var vals = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i+=2) {
            var record = [rows.get(i), rows.get(i+1)]; //Record is two rows.
            var sub = record[r].children[c].innerText; //This is our sort subject.

            vals.push({"sub": sub, "record": record});
        }

        vals.sort(compare);

        for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; ++i) {
            var val = vals[i];
            sorted.appendChild(val.record[0]);
            sorted.appendChild(val.record[1]);
        }

        return sorted;
    }

    function compare(a, b) {
        var atext = a.sub.toLowerCase();
        var btext = b.sub.toLowerCase();
        return atext < btext ? -1 : atext > btext ? 1 : 0;
    }
})();
```

This makes each `TH` element in the `THEAD` element, sortable. It sorts it based on a textual, lowercased, comparison.

It is hard coded to only work with records that are 2 row sets, but could be expanded to allow the configuration of how many rows make up a single record, or even deduce this automagically by counting how many rows are in the `THEAD`.

I used this on the following HTML:

```
<table id="jackpotwatch">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th colspan="2">Full Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Asset</th>
            <th>Patron ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Salem</td>
            <td colspan="2">Bob galvin</td>
            <td>$3400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>assert1</td>
            <td>1148</td>
            <td>sjauser</td>
            <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>chennai</td>
            <td colspan="2">sally n safer</td>
            <td>$400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sdfsdgt1</td>
            <td>4747</td>
            <td>sjauser</td>
            <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mazdgfdg</td>
            <td colspan="2">afdagadg</td>
            <td>789769</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>qwqeqe</td>
            <td>47467</td>
            <td>sjauser</td>
            <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hurtyry</td>
            <td colspan="2">afadfadg</td>
            <td>$12000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>afadsf</td>
            <td>25426546</td>
            <td>sjauser</td>
            <td>11/12 10:39 AM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Make sure to place the script either after the HTML, or in a ready event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Sorting code from above goes here.
});
```

Comment: Really useful. Looking into this solution. I think need to add sorting condition for date foramt. Thank you so much.