# Javascript plugin to do sorting functionality over a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a table which is loading in AJAX, all the data are coming from server side when I click a button from client side. Now I need a sorting functionality in this html table. I have searched and found 5-6 javascript plugins for sorting, but none of them are working. Some are becoming very slow, and some are showing errors. My html table structure is also bit different. Can anyone please help me out to and provide a good js plugin to implement in my code. I am attaching an image of my table structure.

[image]

Basically the table has 2 header rows, I need the sorting functionality over the second header row.

If the image is not clear you can  refer to this link.
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b72bfy588

Comment: yes better to use datable : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: @Sandeep Refer this question [Table sorting with two rows of header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896548/table-sorting-with-two-rows-of-header) it also have similar requirement.

Comment: @sandeep, the link, as of today, is broken. It brings you to the main website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried datatables?

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Usage is simple

http://datatables.net/usage/

Comment: In order for DataTables to be able to function correctly, the HTML for the target table must be laid out in a well formed manner with the 'thead' and 'tbody' sections declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Google DataTable or Jquery Datatable, which priovides sorting.. rest you can customize
```

Comment: Storngly recommend to use Google Datatable.. easy and customizable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin for sorting your table?

$("#myTable").tablesorter();

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: I have already tried with tablesorter , not working for me with my table structure.