# tablesorter with stacked header and data

Tags: header, tablesorter, stacked

Is there any one use tablesorter with stacked header and data?
Two rows are split from one line. Here is the fiddle:

[Stacked header and column per 2 rows](http://jsfiddle.net/0av1e5vy/13/)

css:

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1) { color: green; }
tr:nth-child(4n+2) { color: green; }
tr:nth-child(4n+3) { color: red; }
tr:nth-child(4n+4) { color: red; }
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: it means column 1 - column 8 have 4 lines but I split each line to two lines, what I want is when I click column: 
shows:
**column 1 asc:**
column 1 line 1
column 5 line 1
column 1 line 2
column 5 line 2
column 1 line 3
column 5 line 3
column 1 line 4
column 5 line 4
**column 1 desc:**
column 1 line 4 
column 5 line 4
column 1 line 3
column 5 line 3
column 1 line 2
column 5 line 2
column 1 line 1
column 5 line 1

**If I click column 5 asc:**
column 5 line 1
column 1 line 1
column 5 line 2
column 1 line 2
column 5 line 3
column 1 line 3 
column 5 line 4
column 1 line 4

Comment: I use split one line into 2 lines due to my table has many columns, that's only simple example originally it can split into 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what it is you're asking, make the new second row a child row of the first ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/0av1e5vy/14/)):

```
<tr>
    <td>Column 1 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 2 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 3 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 4 line 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
    <td>Column 5 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 6 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 7 line 1</td>
    <td>Column 8 line 1</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But I need column 1 can be sort so  I removed  class="sorter-false" and column 1 and 5 not worked as expected, this request very difficult because old style using asp and send query to database but this table runs on client, all columns can be sorted and I have one line split into 3 columns due to screen cannot handle many columns ( can have above 16 column per table) in one line.

Comment: I'm still confused... you want that a click on the second row will sort differently than a click on the first row in the same column?

Comment: actually column1 and column 5 are in the same line  but need is to custom the sort mechanism otherwise I have to use database order by instead of client sort, I have one table consist of above 16 columns  due to screen only max 12 columns I split to colum1 - column 8 and column 9 -  column 16 so the row(td) must be split to
row 1 column 1-column8
row 1 column 9-column16
row 2 column 1-column8
row 2 column 9-column16
now I'm trying to build custom sort. still in testing in jsfiddle

Comment: similiar to this question: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896548/table-sorting-with-two-rows-of-header%5C).